# Expanding $\cos(211\pi)$ in two ways gives $-1$ and $+1$. Which is correct?

Tags: trigonometry

If you have an expression like this one:
$$\cos(211\pi)=\cos(210\pi+\pi)=\cos(\pi)=-1 \tag{1}$$
then you can also have
$$\cos(211\pi)=\cos(209\pi+2\pi)=\cos(2\pi)=1 \tag{2}$$

I mean in theory both are correct? But again there's two different answers, can anyone explain to me which one is the correct one?

Comment: The first one. $\cos((2n+1)\pi)=-1$ for any integer $n$

Answer (score 2):

How do you obtain that $\cos(209π+2π)=\cos(2π)$ when the cosine has a basic period of $2π,$ so that no odd multiple of $π$ is a period for the elementary cosine?

This is your mistake. Both are not correct. Only the first is right.

Answer (score 0):

$211 = 105(2) +1$, so $\cos 211 \pi = \cos ([105 \times 2 \pi] + \pi) = \cos \pi = -1$.

The second statement can be rewritten $211 = 104 (2) + 1 + 2$, but $104(2) + 2 + 1 = 105(2) + 1$, which returns us to the first statement.

As the cosine of an odd function is negative, your second statement that $\cos 211 \pi = 1$ is a contradiction.